# Reset TOTP account

Tags: authentication, two-factor-authentication

I'm trying to login to a test org and see the following prompt.

[image]

I use Authy Desktop app to retrieve my tokens.

Looks like I don't have an account setup for this org though.
I must've set one up and then deleted it on Authy, because I'm not getting the prompt to setup a TOTP service.

How can I "reset" this so that I can hook up this org with Authy again?

Note: I've tried opening up in a private window to no avail

Comment: you can ask an admin to Disconnect TOTP for your user in user details (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_removing_two-factor_key.htm&type=5)

Comment: That did it! Feel free to post as an answer so you can get the credit